# Is it possible to sync messages from Mac to iPhone?

Tags: macos, iphone, messages

I accidentally deleted a conversation on my iPhone but the conversation is still there on my Mac. Is there anyway to sync the two so it reappears on my iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

Not currently. You can provide feedback to Apple here:

- https://www.apple.com/feedback/messages.html

Answer (score 0):

The best alternative for you to do, if you really want to save those messages, is to take screenshots of the messages on your Mac, and sync those photos to your phone. It won't be in the Messages app, but you'll still be able to access them on your phone.